# Warning when running cluster_edge_betweenness in R

Tags: r, igraph

I was trying to do community structure detection based on edge betweenness with igraph package in R. When the edges were weighted, some warning showed up:

Warning messages:

```
1: In cluster_edge_betweenness(g) :
  At community.c:460 :Membership vector will be selected based on the lowest modularity score.
2: In cluster_edge_betweenness(g) :
  At community.c:467 :Modularity calculation with weighted edge betweenness community detection might not make sense -- modularity treats edge weights as similarities while edge betwenness treats them as distances
```

When the edges were not weighted, it worked properly without any warning.

Here's the code for generating the warnings:

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_full_graph(10) %du% make_full_graph(10)
g <- add_edges(g, c(1,11))
E(g)$weight <- seq(1,91)
eb <- cluster_edge_betweenness(g)
```

I wonder what do the warning messages mean. And should I be concerned?

```
Session info:
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] igraph_1.2.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3  magrittr_1.5    tools_3.6.3     pkgconfig_2.0.3
```